# Javascript: string to HTML

Tags: javascript, dom

Given a string like that:

```
<img src="image.png" /><p>some text</p>
```

How can I append it to a dom node without using jQuery?

I can create something like that:

```
  var string = '<img src="image.png" /><p>some text</p>';
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = string;
```

and then append it to a node using `appendChild`, but how can I add only the original string without the wrapping `div`?

**Something like jquery's [parseHTML](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseHTML/), I need something that parses a string and return it as html nodes.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.insertAdjacentHTML) for this task.

**EDIT**

If you need to parse a string to elements, you can do something like this:

```
function parseElements(str) {
    var temp = document.createElement('div'),
        nodes, n,
        elements = [];
    temp.innerHTML = str;
    nodes = temp.childNodes;
    for (n = 0; n < nodes.length; n++) {
        elements.push(nodes[n]);
    }
    return elements;
}
```

Comment: sorry I didn't explained it too well, I'd like to have something that return html nodes, something like jquery's parseHTML

Comment: Well, jQuery seems to create a `documentFragment` and elements (from the string) into it, then it merges the results to a resulting jQuery object.

Comment: and how do they put elements from the string into the fragment? they takes div's child nodes?